# Line up decimal place when using re.sub to replace decimal numbers of varying size

Tags: python, regex, string

It seems to me that the default behavior for replacement of matched strings with a larger string is to begin replacement at the starting position of the matched string ie.

```
import re

string = "Parameter Value:     0.12345"
new = re.sub(r'(\d|\.)+', '%0.5f' % 100.123, string) 
print string+'\n'+new
```

Gives the output:

```
Parameter Value:     0.12345
Parameter Value:     100.12300
```

Which appears to be the default behavior, but is there a way to get:

```
Parameter Value:     0.12345
Parameter Value:   100.12300
```

Instead so that the decimal place is lined up with where it was before replacement?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Decimal alignment formatting in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025379/decimal-alignment-formatting-in-python)

Comment: I don't think it is possible as you are ignoring all spaces till `0.12345` and then replacing it. If you match even the spaces then there may be a chance

Comment: You could split and rejoin using alignment

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Could you elaborate?

Comment: @pbreach, I added an example. You will have to handle different cases but it should give you an idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking a clue from Padraic's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28003211/line-up-decimal-place-when-using-re-sub-to-replace-decimal-numbers-of-varying-si#comment44395483_28003211) I tried this and it's working

```
>>> string = "Parameter Value:     0.12345"
>>> s = string.split(":")
>>> num = 100.123
>>> ":".join([s[0],("%0.5f"%(num)).rjust(len(s[1]))])
'Parameter Value:   100.12300'
>>> string
'Parameter Value:     0.12345'
```

Answer (score 2):

You will have to add more logic deciding whether to ljust or rjust etc.. but this should get you started.  Might pay to move `'{:.5f}'.format(100.123)` outside the regex and use the length of that as a deciding factor

```
import re

s = "Parameter Value:     0.12345"
new = re.sub(r'(\d|\.)+', '{:.5f}'.format(100.123), s)
s = s.split(" ")
new = new.split(" ")
a, b = s[-1], new[-1]
ln = len(max(a, b, key=len))
print("{}{:>{ln}}\n{}{}".format(" ".join(s[:-1]), a, " ".join(new[:-1]), b, ln=ln)))

Parameter Value:      0.12345
Parameter Value:    100.12300
```

Another way is getting the start and end index of the string that is going to be replaced, it is pretty easy adjust the string once you know exactly where the string is and how long the string to be replaced is in comparison to rep:

```
import re
f = 100.123
rep = '{:.5f}'.format(f)
s = "Parameter Value:     0.12345"
inds = next(re.finditer(r'(\d|\.)+', s))
start, end = inds.span()
print(start,end)
(21, 28)
ln = end - start
```

Comment: Even you got `100.12300` ?? But the OP got `100.12000` Is it a typo on the OP's side ?

Comment: @BhargavRao, yep definitely a typo

Comment: (I've stolen your comment) *sorry*

Comment: @BhargavRao, no worries, my answer is just a guide. It was not explainable in a comment.