# How to align positive and negative values along the decimal point in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to write bunch of positive and negative values into a text file as below

```
1      12.203026     2.291063     -0.061603
1      -0.736147     1.353548     -1.347932
6       0.728048     1.348907      0.247566
6      -0.728048     1.348907    -10.247565
1      10.736147     1.353547      1.347932
1      -1.203026    12.291063      0.061604
6      11.583889     0.179143    -10.258947
```

when I am writing that it should be aligned along the decimal points as above. The code I written using following f.write() command and it's out put as below.

```
 f.write('%s    %2.6f   %2.6f   %2.6f\n' % (a, x, y, z ))
```

out put

```
1      12.203026    2.291063    -0.061603
1      -0.736147    1.353548    -1.347932
6      0.728048     1.348907    0.247566
6      -0.728048    1.348907    -10.247565
1      10.736147    1.353547    1.347932
1      -1.203026    12.291063    0.061604
6      11.583889    0.179143    -10.258947
```

Comment: The first column data is actually string?

Comment: I think there is a similar question already posted here.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025379/decimal-alignment-formatting-in-python

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The first number in the format is the total number of characters, not the number before the decimal point. When that number is too small it compensates by dropping all the padding. To get what you want you need to use `%10.6f`, not `%2.6f`. That's 1 for the `-`, 2 for the initial digits, 1 for the decimal point, and 6 digits after the decimal - 1+2+1+6=10.

Answer (score 4):

Suppose I have:

```
>>> li=[['1', 12.203026, 2.291063, -0.061603], ['1', -0.736147, 1.353548, -1.347932], ['6', 0.728048, 1.348907, 0.247566], ['6', -0.728048, 1.348907, -10.247565], ['1', 10.736147, 1.353547, 1.347932], ['1', -1.203026, 12.291063, 0.061604], ['6', 11.583889, 0.179143, -10.258947]]
```

You can right align into a fixed field width in two steps:

```
for a,x,y,z in li:
    x1, y1, z1=['{:2.6f}'.format(e) for e in (x,y,z)]
    print '{} {:>13} {:>13} {:>13}'.format(a, x1, y1, z1 )
```

Prints:

```
1     12.203026      2.291063     -0.061603
1     -0.736147      1.353548     -1.347932
6      0.728048      1.348907      0.247566
6     -0.728048      1.348907    -10.247565
1     10.736147      1.353547      1.347932
1     -1.203026     12.291063      0.061604
6     11.583889      0.179143    -10.258947
```

If you want to specify width and precision in one place, you can do:

```
'{} {:{w}.{p}f} {:{w}.{p}f} {:{w}.{p}f}'.format(a, x, y, z, w=13, p=6 )
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  Any way I have all values in floating variables. in my program I included f.write() in a for loop. Is it possible to align the numbers within that for loop without reading it once again?

Comment: The key component is the two lines with `.format` in them. Just put those in your `for` loop. Replace `print` with `f.write` and add the `\n` to the end