# Formatting numbers so they align on the decimal point

Tags: python, formatting

In Python, I need to format numbers so they align on the decimal point, like so:

```
  4.8
 49.723
456.781
-72.18
  5
 13
```

What is the most straightforward way to do this?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025379/decimal-alignment-formatting-in-python

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't *think* there's a straight-forward way to do it, since you need to know the position of the decimal point in all the numbers before you start printing them. (I just had a look at Caramiriel's link, and some of the links from that page, but I couldn't find anything particularly applicable to this case).

So it looks like you have to do some string-based inspection & manipulation of the numbers in the list. Eg,

```
def dot_aligned(seq):
    snums = [str(n) for n in seq]
    dots = [s.find('.') for s in snums]
    m = max(dots)
    return [' '*(m - d) + s for s, d in zip(snums, dots)]

nums = [4.8, 49.723, 456.781, -72.18]

for s in dot_aligned(nums):
    print(s)
```

**output**

```
  4.8
 49.723
456.781
-72.18
```

---

If you want to handle a list of `float`s with some plain `int`s mixed in, then this approach gets a bit messier.

```
def dot_aligned(seq):
    snums = [str(n) for n in seq]
    dots = []
    for s in snums:
        p = s.find('.')
        if p == -1:
            p = len(s)
        dots.append(p)
    m = max(dots)
    return [' '*(m - d) + s for s, d in zip(snums, dots)]

nums = [4.8, 49.723, 456.781, -72.18, 5, 13]

for s in dot_aligned(nums):
    print(s)
```

**output**

```
  4.8
 49.723
456.781
-72.18
  5
 13
```

---

As Mark Ransom notes in the comments, we can simplify handling `int`s by using `.split`:

```
def dot_aligned(seq):
    snums = [str(n) for n in seq]
    dots = [len(s.split('.', 1)[0]) for s in snums]
    m = max(dots)
    return [' '*(m - d) + s for s, d in zip(snums, dots)]
```

---

Masher mentions in a comment that it can be useful to add padding on the right so that the numbers can be printed in aligned columns. However, we don't need to compute the size of that padding for each string, we can use the [`str.ljust`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.ljust) method.

```
def dot_aligned(seq):
    snums = [str(n) for n in seq]
    dots = [len(s.split('.', 1)[0]) for s in snums]
    m = max(dots)
    left_pad = [' '*(m - d) + s for s, d in zip(snums, dots)]
    ms = max(map(len, left_pad))
    return [s.ljust(ms) for s in left_pad]

nums = [4.8, 49.723, 456.781, -72.18, 5, 13, 1.2345] * 3
cols = 4
# Get number of cells in the output grid, using ceiling division
size = len(nums) // -cols * -cols

padded = dot_aligned(nums)
for i in range(0, size, cols):
    print(*padded[i:i+cols])
```

**output**

```
  4.8     49.723  456.781  -72.18  
  5       13        1.2345   4.8   
 49.723  456.781  -72.18     5     
 13        1.2345   4.8     49.723 
456.781  -72.18     5       13     
  1.2345
```

Comment: Instead of `s.find('.')` you can use `len(s.split('.')[0])`, that works with `int` too.

Comment: @MarkRansom: Now why didn't _I_ think of that? :) Thanks!

Comment: and if you need to align multiple columns: `def dot_aligned(seq):
    snums = [str(n) for n in seq]
    nums_before_dot = [len(s.split('.', 1)[0]) for s in snums]
    m = max(nums_before_dot)
    left_pad = [' '*(m - d) + s for s, d in zip(snums, nums_before_dot)]
    ms = len(max(left_pad, key=len))
    return [s + " "*(ms - len(s)) for s in left_pad]
`

Comment: @masher Good idea, but we can use the `str.ljust` method for that. See my update. BTW, it's not recommended to post multi-line code in comments because it's so hard to read. And that especially applies to Python code, since the indentation usually gets messed up (but I must admit that you did a pretty good job on the indentation).

Comment: @masher FWIW, I think your `nums_before_dot` name is great, but I didn't use it because I wanted to maintain consistency with the previous versions.

Comment: No worries. I was doing a bunch of playing and I had before and after dot numbers, and it was confusing.

Answer (score 20):

If you know the precision (digits after the decimal point) that you need, and you don't mind having some trailing zeros when whole numbers are used, you could use the new `f-string` in Python 3.6 ([PEP498](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/)):

```
numbers = [4.8, 49.723, 456.781, -72.18, 5, 13]

for number in numbers:
    print(f'{number:9.4f}')
```

**Prints:**

```
  4.8000
 49.7230
456.7810
-72.1800
  5.0000
 13.0000
```

Comment: Note that this method also requires the (maximum given the range of possible numbers) prefix-length to be specified in the format expression.

Answer (score 9):

The easy way to do it, if you don't mind trailing zeroes is this:

```
numbers = [4.8,49.723,456.781,-72.18,5,13]
for f in numbers:
    print('{:>7.3f}'.format(f))
```

Which prints:

```
   4.800
  49.723
 456.781
 -72.180
   5.000
  13.000
```

If you want to get rid of the trailing zeroes, one thing you can do is use the `re.sub` method from the Regular Expressions module:

```
import re

numbers = [4.8,49.723,456.781,-72.18,5,13]
for f in numbers:
    print(re.sub(r'\.?0+$','','{:>7.3f}'.format(f)))
```

Which prints:

```
  4.8
 49.723
456.781
-72.18
  5
 13
```

However, this will give you columns of different widths.  The only difference is spaces, so you can't see it, but if you were doing it as part of a table, it would look like this:

```
import re

numbers = [4.8,49.723,456.781,-72.18,5,13]
for f in numbers:
    print(re.sub(r'\.?0+$','','{:>7.3f}'.format(f)),'|')
```

Prints:

```
  4.8 |
 49.723 |
456.781 |
-72.18 |
  5 |
 13 |
```

To avoid this, if you want to get *really* fancy you can do this:

```
import re

numbers = [4.8,49.723,456.781,-72.18,5,13]
for f in numbers:
    print(re.sub(r'\.?0+$',lambda match: ' '*(match.end()-match.start()),'{:>7.3f}'.format(f)),'|')
```

Which prints:

```
  4.8   |
 49.723 |
456.781 |
-72.18  |
  5     |
 13     |
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: you have to say n in numbers (unless you mean f in fumbers ;-)

Comment: You could shorten the `re.sub` by using a capturing group. It also fails for integers ending with zeroes, so remove the `?` quantifier. `re.sub(r'\.(0+)$', lambda match: ' '*len(match[1]), f'{f:>7:3})`.

Answer (score 6):

In case you know before starting the number of leading spaces and decimal digits you need, as in other responses, the easy way it's

```
    # python 2 version
    numbers = [4.8, 49.723, 456.781, -72.18, 5, 13, 0.1, .6666, 50000, -40000]

    for number in numbers:
        print '{:16.4f}'.format(number).rstrip('0').rstrip('.')
```

```
    # python 3 version
    numbers = [4.8, 49.723, 456.781, -72.18, 5, 13, 0.1, .6666, 50000, -40000]

    for number in numbers:
        print f'{number:16.4f}'.rstrip('0').rstrip('.')
```

Output:

```
          4.8
         49.723
        456.781
        -72.18
          5
         13
          0.1
          0.6666
      50000
     -40000
```

---

As alternative to [PM 2Ring's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32808835/5306152), to dynamically calculate the correct position of dots column you could use one of these solution:

```
# python 3, f-string and .format() mixed version

numbers = [4.8, 49.723, 456.781, -72.18, 5, 13, 0.1, .6666, 50000, -40000]
numbers2string = [str(X) for X in numbers]
numbers_splitted = [X.split(".") for X in numbers2string]
len_max_before = max([len(X[0]) for X in numbers_splitted])
len_max_after = max([len(X[1]) for X in numbers_splitted if len(X) > 1])
len_max_total = len_max_before + len_max_after + 1

for n in numbers:
    numstring = f'{"{0: >#0"}{len_max_total}.{len_max_after}f{"}"}'
    print(numstring.format(n).rstrip('0').rstrip('.'))
```

```
# python 3, .format() version

numbers = [4.8, 49.723, 456.781, -72.18, 5, 13, 0.1, .6666, 50000, -40000]
numbers2string = [str(X) for X in numbers]
numbers_splitted = [X.split(".") for X in numbers2string]
len_max_before = max([len(X[0]) for X in numbers_splitted])
len_max_after = max([len(X[1]) for X in numbers_splitted if len(X) > 1])

for number in numbers2string:
    if '.' in number:
        number = number.split('.')
        print("{number[0]:>{len_max_before}}.{number[1]:<{len_max_before}}".format(
            number=number,
            len_max_before=len_max_before,
            len_max_after=len_max_after
        ))
    else:
        print("{number:>{len_max_before}}".format(
            number=number,
            len_max_before=len_max_before
        ))
```

```
# python 2 version

numbers = [4.8, 49.723, 456.781, -72.18, 5, 13, 0.1, .6666, 50000, -40000]
numbers2string = [str(X) for X in numbers]
numbers_splitted = [X.split(".") for X in numbers2string]
len_max_before = max([len(X[0]) for X in numbers_splitted])
len_max_after = max([len(X[1]) for X in numbers_splitted if len(X) > 1])

for number in numbers2string:
    if '.' in number:
        number = number.split('.')
        print "{number[0]:>{len_max_before}}.{number[1]:<{len_max_before}}".format(
            number=number,
            len_max_before=len_max_before,
            len_max_after=len_max_after
        )
    else:
        print "{number:>{len_max_before}}".format(
            number=number,
            len_max_before=len_max_before
        )
```

```
# python 3 f-string version

numbers = [4.8, 49.723, 456.781, -72.18, 5, 13, 0.1, .6666, 50000, -40000]
numbers2string = [str(X) for X in numbers]
numbers_splitted = [X.split(".") for X in numbers2string]
len_max_before = max([len(X[0]) for X in numbers_splitted])
len_max_after = max([len(X[1]) for X in numbers_splitted if len(X) > 1])

for number in numbers2string:
    if '.' in number:
        number = number.split('.')
        numstring = f"{number[0]:>{len_max_before}}.{number[1]:<{len_max_after}}"
    else:
        numstring = f"{number:>{len_max_before}}"
    print(numstring)
```

Output:

```
     4.8   
    49.723 
   456.781 
   -72.18  
     5
    13
     0.1   
     0.6666
 50000
-40000
```

Answer (score 3):

Using the recipe in Python documentation: https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html#recipes

```
from decimal import Decimal


def moneyfmt(value, places=3, curr='', sep=',', dp='.',
             pos='', neg='-', trailneg=''):
    [...]

numbers = [4.8, 49.723, 456.781, -72.18]
for x in numbers:
    value = moneyfmt(Decimal(x), places=2, pos=" ")
    print("{0:>10s}".format(value))
```

You'll obtain:

```
  4.800
 49.723
456.781
-72.180
```

Comment: Hmm, this code does not work for me as is - Python 3.4.3. *TypeError: non-empty format string passed to object.__format__*

Comment: If you use Py3, see the Py3 documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#recipes

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I did it!

```
def alignDots(number):
    try:
        whole, dec = str(number).split('.')
        numWholeSpaces = 5 - len(whole) # Where 5 is number of spaces you want to theleft
        numDecSpaces   = 3 - len(dec)   # 3 is number of spaces to the right of the dot
        thousands = ' '* Math.abs(numWholeSpaces) + whole
        decimals  = dec + '0'*Math.abs(numDecSpaces)
        print thousands + '.' + decimals  
        return thousands + '.' + decimals  
    except:
        print "Failed to align dots of ",number
        return ' '*5+'ERROR'
```

I like the other solutions, but needed something specific and thought why not share!

Comment: This approach has the benefit of not having to know all the numbers in advance, as long as you know the range of numbers you will encounter.

Answer (score 2):

Fix for decimal places

```
import decimal

numbers = [4.8, 49.723, 456.781, 50, -72.18, 12345.12345, 5000000000000]

dp = abs(min([decimal.Decimal(str(number)).as_tuple().exponent for number in numbers]))
width = max([len(str(int(number))) for number in numbers]) + dp + 1 #including .

for number in numbers:
    number = ("{:"+str(width)+"."+str(dp)+"f}").format(number)
    print number.rstrip('0').rstrip('.') if '.' in number else number
```

---

Corrected to take width into account on request:

```
numbers = [4.8, 49.723, 456.781, 50, -72.18]
width = max([len(str(number)) for number in numbers]) + 1
for number in numbers:
    number = ("{:"+str(width)+".4f}").format(number)
    print number.rstrip('0').rstrip('.') if '.' in number else number
```

---

EDIT: If you want to include integers

```
numbers = [4.8, 49.723, 456.781, 50, -72.18]

for number in numbers:
    number = "{:10.4f}".format(number)
    print number.rstrip('0').rstrip('.') if '.' in number else number
```

---

```
numbers = [4.8, 49.723, 456.781, -72.18]

for number in numbers:
    print "{:10.4f}".format(number).rstrip('0')
```

Comment: This is an excellent light-weight solution for when you don't care about an offset on the left.

Comment: @coding4fun I've edited the code to take left offset into account.

Comment: There is a bug in your most recent version. Try it with `numbers = [4.8, 49.723, 456.781, 50, -72.18, 12345.12345]`. Thanks.

Comment: @coding4fun Ok I think I've fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm terribly late to this, but you can also use math, specifically the properties of logarithms, to figure out the amount of spaces you need to pad all numbers to the proper decimal position.

```
from math import log10

nums = [4.8, 49.723, 456.781, -72.18, 5, 13]

def pre_spaces(nums):
    absmax = max([abs(max(nums)), abs(min(nums))])
    max_predot = int(log10(absmax))
    spaces = [' '*(max_predot-int(log10(abs(num))) - (1 if num<0 else 0)) for num in nums]
    return spaces

for s,n in zip(pre_spaces(nums), nums):
    print('{}{}'.format(s,n))
```

The result is:

```
  4.8
 49.723
456.781
-72.18
  5
 13
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use the Python `[decimal][1]` type.

There is a [recipe](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html#recipes) used to format monetary values.

Why `decimal` type: avoid rounding problems, handle signifiant digits correctly...

Comment: Can you show an example related to this question? I haven't understand how to properly format a list of numbers aligned to decimal point using decimal type.

Comment: I understood there was a need to avoid leading zero. In any case I think you should avoid multiple answers, as described [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251070/are-multiple-answers-by-the-same-user-acceptable?rq=1).

Answer (score 0):

Yes there are many direct ways by which you can align floating point figures about decimal point. Below given 2 line code is one example

`In [20]: floating=([.022,12.645,544.5645,.54646,-554.56,-.2215,-546.5446])

In [21]: for xxx in floating: print "{0: 10.4f}".format(xxx)
`

Here in {0: 10.4f} 0 is the dimension of each floating point entries. After colon the space is for the optional minus sign. 10 is for number of places before decimal and 4 is for number of places after decimal.
Here is my out put as a JPG [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPNgf.png)

Answer (score 0):

Most answers make a string first, then split it on the decimal to do some further manipulation.  The number can also be split into its whole and decimal parts by using `div` and `mod`.  A solution could then look like this:

```
for x in [4.8, 49.723, 456.781, -72.18,  5, 13]:

    print('[{:s}{}{:4s}]'.format('{:6.0f}'.format(x//1),
                                 '.' if x%1 else ' ',
                                 '{:0.4f}'.format(x%1).strip('.0')))
```

which produces:

```
[     4.8   ]
[    49.723 ]
[   456.781 ]
[   -73.82  ]
[     5     ]
[    13     ]
```

If you can tolerate a trailing decimal you can simplify further by dropping the if/else part in the middle.