# Extract coordinates from Slic3r gcode to text x,y,z,e,f

Tags: python

I'm trying to read a gcode file and use the coordinates on it. But when I run it, the values ​​of each coordinate (X,Y,Z,E,F) presented must be in the same column, which is not happening,

```
import re

with open('novoteste.gcode') as gcode:
    for line in gcode:
        line = line.strip()
        coord = re.findall(r'[XYZEF].?\d+.\d+', line)
        if coord:
            print(f"{coord[0]} - {coord[1]} - {coord[-1]} ")
```

This the result:

```
Z0.400 - F7800.000 - F7800.000 
E-2.000 - F2400.000 - F2400.000 
X89.202 - Y89.018 - F7800.000 
E2.000 - F2400.000 - F2400.000 
X90.699 - Y87.561 - F1800.000 
X92.235 - Y86.138 - E2.49678 
X93.757 - Y84.793 - E2.73796 
X95.322 - Y83.475 - E2.98105 
X96.931 - Y82.184 - E3.22599 
X98.583 - Y80.924 - E3.47273
```

This is the original file:

```
G1 Z0.400 F7800.000
G92 E0
G1 X89.202 Y89.018 F7800.000
G1 E2.00000 F2400.000
G1 X90.699 Y87.561 E2.24810 F1800.000
G1 X92.235 Y86.138 E2.49678
G1 X93.757 Y84.793 E2.73796
G1 X95.322 Y83.475 E2.98105
G1 X96.931 Y82.184 E3.22599
G1 X98.583 Y80.924 E3.47273
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Formatting Numbers So They Align On Decimal Point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32808383/formatting-numbers-so-they-align-on-decimal-point)

Comment: No, because I need columns with the variable separate by variables(x,y,z,e,f) Tks

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "variable separate[d] by variables". Can you please show an example of what you want to achieve? And please include actual and desired output as text, not as a link to an image.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of experience, I edit my question , Is more clear now!!